# React-native: do some code when animation is finished

Tags: react-native

I would like to do some code when animation is finished. How can I do it?
My example:

```
showMsg(){

            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(
                    this.state.bottom,
                    {
                        toValue: 0,
                        duration: 500
                    }),
                Animated.delay(1000),
                Animated.timing(this.state.bottom,
                    {
                        toValue: -50,
                        duration: 500
                    }),
            ]).start();

    }
```

When last animation is finished I wish to do this code:

```
this.setState({
                msg: '',
            });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start()` method takes an optional function which is called when the animation finishes (or is stopped). So you can do:

```
animations.start(result => {
  if (result.finished) {
    this.setState({ msg: 'finished' });
  }
});
```